# SQL Stored Procedure unknown Error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a SQL stored procedure that will be called in Access.  My sp will be passed four data fields(BatchID, InstrumentName, FileName,QueueId). Then it will insert a record into a table (tblinstrumentInterfaceLog).  Here is my code thus far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog @BatchID int, @InstrumentName nvarchar(60), @FileName nvarchar(60), @QueueID int 
INSERT INTO tblInstrumentinterfaceLog (batchId,Instrumentname,"Filename",QueueID,DateOfBatch,folder)
   VALUES (@batchid,@InstrumentName,@FileName,@QueueID,@getdate(),'New')
GO
```

I believe I have the correct format but I get two errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.

Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog, Line 3
Must declare the scalar variable "@QueueID".
```

To Make sure there wasn't perhaps a datatype issue I looked at the schema of tblInstrumentInterfaceLog and this it seemed to match the way I initialized each.

[image]

Could someone tell me if they see an issues with this stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an AS after your parameter declarations and your @getdate() command is just getdate()

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog 
@BatchID int, @InstrumentName nvarchar(60), @FileName nvarchar(60), @QueueID int 

AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tblInstrumentinterfaceLog (batchId,Instrumentname,"Filename",QueueID,DateOfBatch,folder)
   VALUES (@batchid,@InstrumentName,@FileName,@QueueID,
           getdate(),'New')

END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `AS`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE upInsertToInstrumentInterfaceLog @BatchID int, @InstrumentName nvarchar(60),
@FileName nvarchar(60), @QueueID int
AS
INSERT INTO tblInstrumentinterfaceLog (batchId,Instrumentname,"Filename",QueueID,DateOfBatch,folder)
   VALUES (@batchid,@InstrumentName,@FileName,@QueueID,@getdate(),'New')
GO
```

Comment: oh of course! I was only focusing on the insert statement syntax